# Topological filters in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm studying topological filters in `Filter.thy`

```
theory Filter
imports Set_Interval Lifting_Set
begin

subsection ‹Filters›

text ‹
  This definition also allows non-proper filters.
›

locale is_filter =
  fixes F :: "('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool"
  assumes True: "F (λx. True)"
  assumes conj: "F (λx. P x) ⟹ F (λx. Q x) ⟹ F (λx. P x ∧ Q x)"
  assumes mono: "∀x. P x ⟶ Q x ⟹ F (λx. P x) ⟹ F (λx. Q x)"

typedef 'a filter = "{F :: ('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool. is_filter F}"
proof
  show "(λx. True) ∈ ?filter" by (auto intro: is_filter.intro)
qed
```

I don't get this definition. It's quite convoluted so I'll simplify it first

The expression
`F (λx. P x)` could be simplified to `F P` (using [eta reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) of lambda calculus). The predicate `'a ⇒ bool` is really just a set `'a set`. Similarly `('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool` should be `'a set set`. Then we could rewrite the axioms as

```
assumes conj: "P ∈ F ∧ Q ∈ F ⟹ Q ∩ P ∈ F"
assumes mono: "P ⊆ Q ∧ P ∈ F ⟹ Q ∈ F"
```

Now my question is about the `True` axiom. It is equivalent to

```
assumes True: "UNIV ∈ F"
```

This does not match with the definitions of filters that I ever saw.
The axiom should be instead

```
assumes True: "{} ∉ F"  (* the name True is not very fitting anymore *)
```

The statement `UNIV ∈ F` is unnecessary because it follows from axiom `mono`.

So what's up with this definition that Isabelle provides?

Comment: I'm no expert in topology, but I'll try to help a bit with your question: The `Filter` theory file has an initial remark stating that the definition also allows non-proper filters, and that seems to be the reason for the `True` assumption. The following article by the authors of the `Filter` theory might further clarify the design decisions: https://www.cs.vu.nl/~jhl890/pub/hoelzl2013typeclasses.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided by Javier Diaz has lots of explanations.

Turns out this is a definition of improper filter. The axiom `True` is necessary and does not follow from `mono`. If this axiom was missing then `F` could be defined as

```
F P = False
```

or in set-theory notation, `F` could be an empty set and `mono` and `conj` would then be satisfied vacuously.

Comment: The reason why we define improper filters is that they form a complete lattice (i.e. you have a greatest filter and a least filter and any set of filters, even infinite ones, have a unique supremum and infimum). This makes a lot of the reasoning about them much nicer. Some theorems that do require a proper filter then simply have `F ≠ bot` as a precondition.